# Custom preference screen

Tags: android

I have a slider for the user to control the volume of my application. What I'd like to have is a icon or something else similar to "volume display" like in the next picture at the slider summary. Is this possible ? How could this be accomplished ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should look into OpenIntents slider implementation for inspiration. More on it at http://code.google.com/p/openintents/source/browse/trunk/openintents/src/org/openintents/widget/Slider.java